# How to fix "missing FROM-clause entry for table" error

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I'm trying to get the name of platforms based on games id.

I have three tables as below and I'm trying to JOIN them to get result that needed:

```
      Games

Id | .....| .....|
---|------ ------|
1  | .    | .    |
2  | .    | .    |
3  | .    | .    |
4  | .    | .    |

      Game_Platforms

Id |....|game_id| platform_id|...|
---------------------------------
1  | .  | 1     |   1        |.. |
2  | .  | 1     |   2        |.. |
3  | .  | 3     |   3        |.. |
.. | .  | 4     |   4        |.. |

    Platforms
Id| ...|...| name    |
---------------------|
1 | .  | . | iOS     |
2 | .  | . | Android |
3 | .  | . | Windows |
4 | .  | . | SteamOS |
```

```
type Platforms struct {
   Name string
}

var name []Platforms

query = postgres.Db().Select("name").
        Joins("JOIN games ON games.id = game_platforms.game_id").
        Joins("JOIN game_platforms ON game_platforms.platform_id = platforms.id").
        Where("games.id = 1").Find(&name)
```

I expect to get the Platforms name, but get the error:

> pq: missing FROM-clause entry for table "game_platforms"

I think that I wrote Joins commands incorrect, but it seems logical, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: What for? I've removed my comment since you've solved your issue, however there isn't anything in the question's tags that would answer the question in that comment.

Comment: @mkopriva sorry my bad, didn't want to get anybody confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer to my question wasn't without of support of @novalagung
Credit to him, so i need to change query to look like this

```
query = postgres.Db().Select("name").
    Joins("JOIN game_platforms ON game_platforms.platform_id = platforms.id").
    Joins("JOIN games ON games.id = game_platforms.game_id").
    Where("games.id = 1").Find(&name)
```

However I had an error that said **pq: column reference "name" is ambiguous**
But it is my fault because I didn't specified in question all tables, so small changes need to be done to solve this error is ***Select("platforms.name").***

Answer (score 2):

You query is missing the `FROM` clause.

I assume you wanted to select the data from `platforms` table. If it is, then (as per your code) you shall join with the `game_platforms` first then with the `games`.

```golang
query = postgres.Db().Select("name").
    Find("platforms"). // <------ this one
    Joins("JOIN game_platforms ON game_platforms.platform_id = platforms.id").
    Joins("JOIN games ON games.id = game_platforms.game_id").
    Where("games.id = 1").Find(&name)
```

Comment: I think you need to change join places also

Comment: but description is incorrect `you shall join with the game_platforms first then with the games`

Comment: From doesn't work, because **Find** in query add From